# Programmatically changed attribute is not visible on frontend (product list)

Tags: attributes, eav, ee-1.13.1.0

We have a custom attribute which is added to the default attribute group. Used in product listing is yes and it is added in the `config.xml` to the product collection.

The values of the attribute are set using `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action::updateAttributes` in a data upgrade script.

Anyways, the values are not displayed in the product listing. When the product is saved in the backend, it becomes visible.

Rebuilding all indices using `indexer.php` or `n98-magerun.phar` did not help.

*EDIT*

**data upgrade script 1**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$attrCodeDeliveryTimeFrom = 'delivery_time_from';
$attrCodeDeliveryTimeTo = 'delivery_time_to';
$attrGroupName = 'General';
$attrLabelDeliveryTimeFrom = 'Delivery time from (days)';
$attrLabelDeliveryTimeTo = 'Delivery time to (days)';
$attrNoteDeliveryTimeFrom = 'Days from';
$attrNoteDeliveryTimeTo = 'Days to';

$objCatalogEavSetup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_mysql4_setup', 'core_setup');
$attrIdTest = $objCatalogEavSetup->getAttributeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCodeDeliveryTimeFrom);

if ($attrIdTest === false) {
    $objCatalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCodeDeliveryTimeFrom, array(
    'group' => $attrGroupName,
    'sort_order' => 50,
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => $attrLabelDeliveryTimeFrom,
    'note' => $attrNoteDeliveryTimeFrom,
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'is_configurable' => false,
    'used_for_promo_rules' => true
    ));
}

$attrIdTest = $objCatalogEavSetup->getAttributeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCodeDeliveryTimeTo);

if ($attrIdTest === false) {
    $objCatalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCodeDeliveryTimeTo, array(
    'group' => $attrGroupName,
    'sort_order' => 51,
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => $attrLabelDeliveryTimeTo,
    'note' => $attrNoteDeliveryTimeTo,
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'is_configurable' => false,
    'used_for_promo_rules' => true
    ));
}

$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product','delivery_time');
```

**date upgrade script 2**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter(2);
$storeId = 0;

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
    $data = array(
    'delivery_time_to' => 3,
    'delivery_time_from' => 1
    );
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), $data, $storeId);
}


$installer->endSetup();
```

We did the attribute creation in a data upgrade script. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Is just the value not display or the whole product missing?

Comment: @Tobias: The value is missing.

Comment: ok i had similar issues with complete product missing. i know that's not your problem. anyway i would suggest check if there exists an attribute value for store_id 0, at least in earlier magento version this lead to that error. if you have specific store values, you needed at least a NULL entry as value for store_id=0. this just as comment as it's just an idea and not guaranteed to work, sorry ;)

Comment: Do you happen to use flat tables for products? If so, make sure your catalog_product_flat_1, 2, 3... have populated values for your attribute.

Comment: Flat tables are off.

Comment: Is it sure that the attribute is assigned to the product's attribute set? Also, could you post the exact code snippet that should set & save the attribute value?

Comment: *edited* we did the attribute in a data upgrade script. Maybe this might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex,

This is missing in your attribute data:
    **'used_in_product_listing' => true**

Please try by adding that in your code. I tried and it works.

---

```
if ($attrIdTest === false) {
    $objCatalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCodeDeliveryTimeFrom, array(
    'group' => $attrGroupName,
    'sort_order' => 50,
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => $attrLabelDeliveryTimeFrom,
    'note' => $attrNoteDeliveryTimeFrom,
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'is_configurable' => false,
    'used_for_promo_rules' => true
    ));
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

**In date upgrade script 2** you have used below filter in product collection. i would suggest removing that.

```
->addStoreFilter(2);
```

And Second thing

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), $data, $storeId);
```

will only save a single attribute in one go.

instead of that use `$product->save();`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be causing the issue is that you filter by the store id 2 and then save the attribute on the store id 0.

I am not sure how this could cause an issue but maybe it messes around because the product object is loaded and attached to store 2.