# Non default store_view's product attribute value is not visible on frontend (product list) if store_view 0 EAV value is missing

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, product-attribute, eav, flat-catalog

**Scenario**: A Magento 1.7 store which has NO default values at all for some product attributes (like *short_description*). There is no entry in *catalog_product_entity_text* for *store_view*==0. (Even NO entry with NULL)

(**Background**: The product attribute values are generated programmatically from some external source. Without any store_view 0 values. For whatever reason.)

**Problem**: The (well defined) product attribute value of the non-default store_view (e.g. store_view 2) is not visible in catalog product list.

**Workaround**: The store_view 2 value is displayed if we define a value for store_view 0 in *catalog_product_entity_text*. (E.g. NULL)

Following comment mentions a bug in "older" Magento versions:
[Programmatically changed attribute is not visible on frontend (product list)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23694/programmatically-changed-attribute-is-not-visible-on-frontend-product-list#comment33499_23694)

Also the indexer does not work: The attribute's value in *catalog_product_flat_2* table is null.

**Question**: Is there any solution to allow empty or not defined store_view 0 product attribute values on "older" Magento versions?

(Of course "*used_in_product_listing*" is set to 1. And *backend_type* of the attribute short_description is "text".)